# Coordinate systems in HTML/CSS for different positioning schemes

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've been studying HTML/CSS and, while reading the article [CSS Positioning 101](https://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101), I came upon this statement:

> a static element can’t even create a new coordinate system for child
>   elements

Then the author also states:

> Creating a coordinate system for child elements is another one of the
>   relative positioning property’s super powers

Ok. That's relatively simple to understand, I thought. So I made some predictions and wanted to test them to be sure I got it right.

At that same page, the author provide some examples, so I altered them a little bit. [Example D](https://alistapart.com/d/css-positioning-101/example_d.html) was altered as follows:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Example D</title>
  <style>
    #box_1 {
      position: static;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: #ee3e64;
    }
    
    .box_2 { /*made it into a class*/
      position: relative;
      left: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: #44accf;
    }
    
    #box_3 {
      position: static;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: #b7d84b;
    }
  </style>
  <meta id="dcngeagmmhegagicpcmpinaoklddcgon">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box_1">
    <div class="box_2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="box_3">
    <div class="box_2"></div>
    <!-- created a new box_2 inside box_3 -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For me the result was unexpected.

[image]

I predicted, since box_3 is a static element (and therefore establishes no new coordinate system), the box_2 inside it should be exactly at the same place as the first box_2, as both of them would use the document's coordinate system as a reference. Instead, the second box_2 was shifted 200px as if the static element box_3 had indeed created a new coordinate system for its children, counter to what the author stated.

So I got very confused. I also made some tests with absolute-positioned elements and the results also didn't make much sense to me.

Did I just get all wrong or is this article and are these statements simply false? If I got it wrong, what does the author mean by "create a new coordinate system"?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. Example D in the article does not demonstrate the new coordinate system as it claims to do.

Positioned elements, that is elements that have a position value other than `static`, which obviously includes, but is not limited to `relative` positioned elements, establish a new coordinate system for their **absolute** positioned descendants. So for descendants of relative positioned elements that have `position:absolute`, their `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` property values are offsets from that relative positioned element.

But in example D, both box_1 and box_2 are relatively positioned. Box_1 may establish a new coordinate system for its descendants, but box_2 does not use it. Since box_2 is `position:relative`, its `left`, `top`, etc values move the element from the position it would have had in normal flow, and are not taken from any new coordinate system.

Therefore box_1 could have been `position:static` without changing the final location of box_2.

See comments [20](https://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101#330010) and [32](https://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101#330038) on the article.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response and for pointing out the author's mistake. Still, I tried changing .box_2 to position: absolute in my altered example above and the results were the same. If absolute positioning depends on the new coordinate system of its parent, then, since the parents of both box_2 elements are static elements, and thus have no coordinate system of their own, both box_2 elements should be at exactly the same place. What concept did I get wrong or what is the flaw of my logic?

Comment: I think your test is wrong. You have both box_1 and box_3 as `position:static`. I think you intended one or the other to be `position:relative`.